# float() argument must be a string or a number in Stochastic Gradient Descent of scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to use svm classifier for text classification,

```
self.clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(alpha=1e-3,loss="hinge", penalty="l2")
data_folder = self.root_dir + "/trec_data"
train_dataset = load_files(data_folder)
for text in self.data_train.data:
    text = self.modifyQuery(text.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
    training_data.append(text)
raw_X = (self.token_ques(text) for text in training_data)
rbf_feature = RBFSampler(gamma=1, random_state=1)
X_train = rbf_feature.fit_transform(raw_X)
y_train = self.data_train.target
```

which gives me error at `X_train = rbf_feature.fit_transform(raw_X)`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classifier_lessClass.py", line 167, in trainClassifier
    X_train = rbf_feature.fit_transform(np.array(raw_X))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.16b1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sklearn/base.py", line 433, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.16b1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sklearn/kernel_approximation.py", line 76, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scikit_learn-0.16b1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 341, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I tried with converting `raw_X` to float() but still same error. Also tried with `np.array(raw_X)` which gives same error.

Comment: What is the data type of the elements of raw_X?  In other words, what is returned by the function self.token_ques?  That's the issue, because apparently the list raw_X doesn't contain objects that can be converted to float().

Comment: @PaulCornelius: data type of `raw_X` is `generator` and `self.token_que` return tocknized str of text

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a "tocknized str" is.  Tokenizing a string, if that's what you mean, generally entails converting it to a list of sub-strings.  Such a list is not "a string or a number," which is consistent with the error message.

Comment: You need to convert your data to a numeric format, possibly using CountVectorizer. Look at the text processing tutorial: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html